# Regarding Joomla 3 Multilingual Component Development

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I am about to start developing a Joomla 3 multilingual component but I have a question so that I should be aware of upcoming challenges

Question: Let's assume, Joomla CMS is installed with en-US and fr-FR languages only. Now, if I try install a component which is only available in es-ES and pt-BR languages then how Joomla CMS will react to the component?

1. Component will not install at all
2. Component will install(or install with errors) and it will appear in es-ES language by using available language files for that particular component even though es-ES language is not installed in Joomla CMS
3. By Default, values passed to JText::_() function will appear (such as COM_COMPOENENT_NAME_STRING)
4. If none of above then what output I can except?

Answer (score 0):

I belive you can test this using the following recipe:

- Make a clean joomla install
- Install a component with only the es-ES - language
- Go look in the component admin interface to se what language comes out.
- Try some different settings, to see if they have effect, f.ex. set es-ES as the default admin language, default frontend language etc.

In general, this language handling in Joomla affects only the admin-interface and frontend styling/headers of the component, not the content you add to the component. To translate frontend-output of a component is usually not a very big job. A bit more if you also have to translate all administrator-language-files, but this will also be a doable job that seldom takes more than a few hours on a moderately sized component.

Answer (score 0):

I think the scenario you are describing is unlikely because most components will come at least with English and if that is your main language it will show that language. But for arguments sake, let's look at it.

So first we have to define what is your main source language. Let's say it is Spanish to make the example valid. Let's say you have Spanish, English and French installed in Joomla. Joomla ships with English but you can unpublish it.

If you install a component that is developed correctly but does not have language files for French but do have one for Spanish you would see the Spanish correctly and the French you would see COM_COMPOENENT_NAME_STRING. It would be relatively simple to translate the language file to French simply by creating the appropriate language file.

If you do, consider sending it to the component developer so they can include it in future releases.

The above only applies to language strings stored in the language files. If the component stores any data in the database it needs to be developed specifically for multilingual use (which most are not) or you need to use a translation component such as http://www.neno-translate.com

If you use Neno it will display the source language of any string (file or database) until it has been translated.

Note: I work for www.neno-translate.com and I am declaring my affiliation as it is required by Stackoverflow, but I would also like to clarify that it is the only solution that can translate any 3rd party component so referencing it is valid. Also it is free and open source!